# Extract TextString between second and third hyphen

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract some information from a string in one of my columns with a RegEx.

I need to define a second column equal to what is between the 2nd and 3rd occurrence of a hyphen in my first column.

After much googling around I managed to get this far:

`IFNULL(SAFE.REGEXP_EXTRACT(Final.CampaignName, r"(?:\w+\s+-\s+){2}(\w+)\s+-"), "Other") AS CampaignCategory`

Example of how a string of in Final.CampaignName could look:

S - Oranges - Bar - Apples

S - Apples - Foo Bar - Oranges - Bananas

S - Apples - Bar

My Regex will only return the value if there is 1 word between the 2nd and 3rd hyphens, but I need to have the entire text returned (minus leading and trailing whitespace).

Can anyone guide me in the right direction to doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit to clarify what is to be returned for each of your examples. It's obvious for the first two. For the third there is no text between the second and third hyphen (because there is no third hyphen), so what is to be returned? An empty string? An error? If you want `Bar` returned you need to revise the wording of your question. Different answers have made different assumptions about this.

Comment: based on context - I strongly feel that output for third example should be Bar. obviously this is assuming context is correctly represented.

Comment: My apologies. I did indeed expect the third example to return the `Bar` as well. Thank you for the answers below from both of you. 
Cary helped me understand RegEx better and Mikhail had the perfect answer for my BQ example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I were almost there - so, below is as close to your original idea as I could get (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT IFNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT(final.CampaignName, r"(?: - .*?){2}(.*?)(?: -|$)"), "Other") AS CampaignCategory
```

Answer (score 3):

If the regex engine supports `\K` (loosely, forget everything matched so far), one could use the following regular expression to match the text between the second and third hyphen.

```
^(?:[^-]+-){2}\K[^-]+(?=-)
```

Note that this regex does not contain a capture group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GsIpCU/1/)

This does not match `Bar` in the third example because there are only two hyphens. To match `Bar` simply remove the lookahead `(?=-)`.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^           match beginning of line
(?:[^-]+-)  match 1+ chars other than '-' followed by '-'
            in a non-capture group
{2}         execute non-capture group twice
\K          discard everything matched so far (reset the starting
            point of the reported match)
[^-]+       match 1+ chars other than '-'
(?=-)       match '-' in a positive lookahead
```

If `[^-]` is not to match newlines change it to `[^-\r\n]`.

If `\K` is not supported, a capture group is needed (and the lookahead is not):

```
^(?:[^-]+-){2}([^-]+)-
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the thorough explanation, Cary!

Comment: The `REGEXP_EXTRACT` supports capture groups, so your first method is not needed.

Comment: @Tim, I assumed that was the case, but as others, including yourself, had given solutions that used capture groups, I thought I'd suggest something different, largely for educational reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following pattern with a capture group to isolate what you really want to extract:

```
SAFE.REGEXP_EXTRACT(Final.CampaignName, r"[^-]+-[^-]+-\s*([^-]+?)\s*-") AS CampaignCategory
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

You could match what is between the second and third hyphen using a capturing group and make matching the rest optional using a repeating pattern with `*`

```
\w+(?:\s+-\s+\w+)\s+-\s+(\w+(?: \w+)*)(?:\s+-\s+\w+)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IZu3z3/1)

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer the other way if possible, instead of using Regex.
So for your problem, I can recommend that code:

```
split(Final.CampaignName, ' - ')[safe_offset(2)]
```

An example with your sample data:

```
select campaignName, split(campaignName, ' - ')[safe_offset(2)] as third_item
from unnest(['S - Oranges - Bar - Apples', 'S - Apples - Foo Bar - Oranges - Bananas', 'S - Apples - Bar']) as campaignName
```

Output looks like:
[image]